# Can I use: "We only have known them for a short time"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I use a sentence with this structure?

> We **only** *have* known them for a short time

or needs to be?

> We *have* **only** known them for a short time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to placing "**only**" in a sentence lies in choosing the part of the sentence to focus on. "only" places focus on the word, phrase or clause that comes right after.

The original sentence is:

> We have known them for a short time

Now let me explain:

1. We **only** have known them for a short time. - Means that we "have known them for a short time" and not "seen, talked to or fought (for instance)". Thus "*have known*" is focused.
2. We have **only** known them for a short time. Here the focus is on the entire second part "known the for a short time" with a stressed "known".
3. We have known **only** them for a short time. Means that "we have known only them" not someone else, just them "for a short time".
4. We have known them **only** for a short time. Means that "only for a short time" they have known them. Not for a long time.
5. We have known them for **only** a short time. This is quite like the previous one but with an emphasis on "short" rather than the entire part "for a short time".
6. We have known them for a short time **only**. Stresses the entire sentence.

And finally:

7. **Only** we have known them for a short time. Means that it was only us, not someone else who have known them for a short time.